# Seeking of AVPlayer on http live stream(M3U8)

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

If you do seeking again and again,  you will get wrong current play time by AVPlayer's "currentTime" method.

if don't seek, AVPlayer's "currentTime"  is fine.  However, our users often do seeking, and we will lost right current time.  Unfortunately current time is very important for our business.  I have researched every page related with the question at stackoverflow.

No answer. No possible solution.  No any idea.

Stackoverflow is so good website for programer to discuss hard problems. I still keep hope about you, genius guys.

---

```
AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItem = [self.player currentItem];
if (thePlayerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
{

        CMTime nowTime = self.player.currentTime;
}
```

Comment: how you get current time of AVPlayer Show some code

Comment: Apple tell me, the problem is related with m3u8 segment. Bad m3u8 segment or bad m3u8 file is the resource of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple tell me, the problem is related with m3u8 segment. Bad m3u8 segment or bad m3u8 file is the resource of the problem.